# Which method will be called when we hold the UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When we select UITableViewCell than `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` called.

But which method will be called if we hold the UITebleViewCell. Guys my problem is that I have created a tableview which contain large cell and in that cell I am setting various view an view's background color.

When I select the cell, the background color of my cell will be gone. I have solved this problem by setting view background color again in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *vLineview=[selectedCell viewWithTag:1];
    vLineview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(89/255.0) green:(89/255.0) blue:(89/255.0) alpha:1];
}
```

This done the trick and my view background color will displayed but when I hold the UITableViewCell than it will gone again.

How can I solve this? Do I have to and gesture recognizer to detect long touch and implement my view background method in it? Or there is any other method available for that.

Comment: well if there is no use of delegates in your app then why you are using it.Just remove tableview delegate might be it works for you

Comment: @alpha i am not sure what r u suggesting but yes i have use of tableview delegate in my app so i cant remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with set cell selection style none like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UITableViewCell and override this method:

```
- (void) setSelected: (BOOL) selected
            animated: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super setSelected: selected
              animated: animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: Should really be `- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated` for the touch and hold.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an issue with the UITableViewCell remaining selected after you tap on the row?

If row selection is not required, make sure you call `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated` at the end of your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Pleasese see method named `-(void)beginUpdates`

Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously.
for more detail visit apple documentation in below link 

[UITableView Class Refrence](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates)

Also try `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];`